# Android onClickListener for all inflated views

Tags: android

I have ran into a problem where I have somehow made a dead spot where I can't find the view for it  in my app. In that dead spot I need to put a on click listener for that area but I'm unable to find the item.

My question is:

Is there a way to get all of the views that have been inflated for an activity and add a listener to identify which one was clicked?

Comment: `findViewById(R.id.id_view).setOnClickListener` ?

Comment: The problem is that I do not know the id of the item I am clicking on so I cant add a listener to it.

Comment: why don't you  know it ?

Comment: You are creating views or what?? So you don't know the id's.

Comment: I have multiple fragments that are inflated inside of each other. I have tried adding a onClickListener for all of the fragment views that are inflated but none of them are triggered when I click in the dead spot.

Answer (score 1):

You can inflate your view in `onCreate()` set listener for your view 
like

```
yourView.setOnclickListenre(..)
```

Then You can catch click listener in

```
@override
public void onClick(View v)
{
   switch(v.getId())
   {
    case R.id.youViewId1:
      // youViewId1  id view is clicked
      break;

    case R.id.youViewId2:
     // youViewId2  id view is clicked
      break;
   }
}
```

Comment: I have tried adding a onClickListener for all of the fragment views that are inflated but none of them are triggered when I click in the dead spot. The dead spot seems to be the back of a listview, see the image. http://puu.sh/iMKrx/5cfdb87684.png

Comment: Why do you need a click listener there? In any case, maybe, for your case, a ListView isn't what you want. Maybe you want to make this into a LinearLayout.

Comment: I need a listener there because when anything but the bottom bar is clicked, I need to swap that part with a new fragment. I'm also using a listview so I can dynamically add parts. It also has the chance to excess the view space so I need it to be able to scroll down. I don't know if a linear layout will work.

Comment: You could probably accomplish this with a LinearLayout inside of a ScrollView. If you have an onClickListener on the LinearLayout and also the other views, it is likely that the other views will consume the click and so the LinearLayout is only clicked when blank space is is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement `View.onClicklistener` in that activity and `override` `onClick` method like below:

```
 Public class MyActivity extends activity implements OnClicklistern {
Public void onCreate(....) {
//here you can inflate view and add setOnclicklister to every view to this activity
}

@Override
Public void OnClicklistern(View view) {
Switch (c.getid()) {
Case R.id.oneview :
//do something
break;
Case R.id.anotherview:
// do something
break;
.......
.......
}
}
}
```